# Couldn't load SIP module - python disabled

Tags: qgis, python, sip

Recently my QGIS started refusing to load SIP module, from day to day without any significant changes in the system (I'm on Windows7 x64). Message thrown at startup:

```
Nie można wczytać modułu SIP. (Couldn't load SIP module)
Wsparcie dla Pythona zostanie wyłączone. (Python support will be disabled)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name wrapinstance

Wersja Pythona: (Python version)
2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Wersja QGIS: (QGIS version)
1.8.0-Lisboa 'Lisboa', f440b60

Lokalizacja Pythona: (Python location)
['C:/PROGRAMS/Geodesy/OSGeo4Win/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/Muciek/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/Muciek/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRAMS/Geodesy/OSGeo4Win/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\qgis\\python', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRAMS\\Geodesy\\OSGeo4Win\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']
```

I tried reinstalling various versions of QGIS (1.7 - 1.9) and manipulated with system Path and PYTHONPATH both with no result.

QGIS starts perfectly on different user account (without administration rights). It means that it may be a problem with sone software installed but still I have no idea what could it be.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve the case. The problem was in
`C:\Users\<Username>\.qgis\python\plugins\sip`
After removing this folder everything got back to normal.
Regards.